# So I have this drag and drop functionality on this page but I want only the files in this format to be uploaded Name-YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss-uuuu.jpeg

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, file-format

So I have this drag and drop functionality on this page but I want only the files in this format to be uploaded Name-YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss-uuuu.jpeg .
currently drag and drop takes any file that ends in jpeg, jpg but I want it only accept this the files that have above file format.

please share you approached it and not only the code solution of it. will you create an object

`

```
import './Historical.css';
import {Divider,Typography } from '@mui/material';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';
import React, {useCallback} from 'react'

const firstthing = {
  Name : "",
  FormData : "YYY-MM-DD_hh_mm_ss_uuuu"

}


 export default function Historical(props) {
  const {
    acceptedFiles,
    fileRejections,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps
  } = useDropzone({
   
    accept: {
      'image/*': ['.jpg','.jpeg' ]
    }


  });

  const SUBDIVIDER_STYLE = { marginTop: '10px', marginBottom: '8px', width: '100%' } 
  
  const acceptedFileItems = acceptedFiles.map(file => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
    </li>
  ));

  const fileRejectionItems = fileRejections.map(({ file, errors }) => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
      <ul>
        {errors.map(e => (
          <li key={e.code}>{e.message}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  ));

  return (
 <div>
      <div>
      <Typography variant="h5" >Historical Images</Typography>
<Divider style={SUBDIVIDER_STYLE} textAlign="center"><Typography style={{ fontWeight: '400' }} variant="h6">Load Historical Images </Typography></Divider>
</div>
  <div className="wrapper">
      <div {...getRootProps({ className: 'banner' })}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <span className="banner_text">Click to Add files </span>
        <span className= "banner_text">Or</span>
        <span className="banner_text">Drag and Drop files here</span>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <ul className=' files_list_item'>{acceptedFileItems}</ul>
      </aside>
    </div>
   
    </div>
  );
}

<Historical />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the files once they are 'accepted'. So, you can use the `onDrop` function to get the uploaded files, and then you can rename or modify the files.

You should also maintain a separate state for the modified files (with the naming convention you want to follow). Your code can be like this:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";

export default function Historical(props) {
  const [uploadedFiles, setUploadedFiles] = useState([]);
  const { acceptedFiles, fileRejections, getRootProps, getInputProps } =
    useDropzone({
      accept: {
        "image/*": [".jpg", ".jpeg"],
      },
      onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
        // set the modified files here
        setUploadedFiles(
          acceptedFiles.map((file) => {
            return Object.defineProperty(file, "name", {
              writable: true,
              value: "Name-YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss-uuuu", // you can rename it here, if you want to use the original file name instead of 'Name' then just use 'file.name'
            });
          })
        );
      },
    });

  // then you should use the 'uploadedFiles' here, instead of 'acceptedFiles'
  const acceptedFileItems = uploadedFiles.map((file) => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
    </li>
  ));

  // your other codes here...
}
```